# pandas - Merge adjacent duplicate rows based on one column value and aggregate the string in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to merge the adjacent messages into one line.

Here is an example,

```
Name   Message
A      hi
A      how are you
B      find , and you ?
A      good
A      have you finished the homework
```

What I want to get like this,

```
Name   Message
A      hi how are you
B      find , and you ?
A      good have you finished the homework
```

Could this be done with `groupby()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can `group` the dataframe on adjacent blocks of duplicate rows and aggregate `Name` using `first` and `Message` using `.join`

```
b = df['Name'].ne(df['Name'].shift()).cumsum()
df.groupby(b, as_index=False).agg({'Name': 'first', 'Message': ' '.join})
```

#### Explanations

`Shift` the `Name` column one unit downwards then compare the shifted column with the non-shifted one to create a boolean mask which can be used to identify the boundaries between adjacent duplicate rows.

```
>>> df['Name'].ne(df['Name'].shift())

0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
Name: Name, dtype: bool
```

Now take the **cumulative** sum on the above boolean mask to identify the blocks of rows where the value in column `Name` stays the same

```
>>> df['Name'].ne(df['Name'].shift()).cumsum()

0    1
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    3
Name: Name, dtype: int64
```

Then `group` the dataframe on the above identfied blocks and aggregate column `Name` using `first` and `Message` using `.join`

```
  Name                              Message
0    A                       hi how are you
1    B                     find , and you ?
2    A  good have you finished the homework
```